# Exporting sql request to csv instead of table data

Tags: sql, oracle, csv

I need to export data from my Oracle table to a csv file.
Below is the code that I am running under SQL Developer :

```
set termout off
set serveroutput off
set feedback off
set colsep ';'
set lines 100000
set pagesize 0
set echo off
set feedback off

spool D:\myfile.csv

select *
from Employee;

spool off
```

However the output of the above code in the csv file is :

> select *
>   from Employee;

I want the data of the Employee table to be in the csv, not the sql statement.
Any idea what might be wrong in the above code?  Thanks.

Comment: You should run this script using SQL*Plus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

save your sql in a file `emp.sql` in a directory `D:\scripts` and use like below;

```
set term off
set feed off

spool D:\myfile.csv

@D:\scripts\emp.sql

spool off
```

Answer (score 0):

You're in SQL Developer, so you don't have to write so much code.

```
SET SQLFORMAT csv
SPOOL C:\your_file.csv
select * from whatever;
spool off
```

Run with F5