# Get Clean Output In Spool With Column Names

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get two columns from a table to print to a csv file, my code currently looks like:

```
set colsep
set headsep off
set pagesize 0
set trimspool on
set heading off
set arraysize 1
set newpage 0
set pages 0
set feedback off
set echo off
set verify off

spool C:\Users\me\Documents\file.csv

select COL_A||','||COL_B from MyTable;

spool off;
```

But the output contains the query itself which I would like to have removed. I also need there to be a header for the two column names, so my output would look like:

```
COL_A | COL_B
-------------
  a   |  1
  b   |  2
  c   |  3
```

Comment: you may refer to this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46357979/exporting-sql-request-to-csv-instead-of-table-data/46358690#46358690

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exporting sql request to csv instead of table data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46357979/exporting-sql-request-to-csv-instead-of-table-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set trimspool on
set heading on
set pages 10000
set lines 300
set feedback off
set echo off
set verify off

spool C:\Users\me\Documents\file.csv

@sqlfile.sql

spool off;
```

sqlfile.sql containing your query